# Go to different url on clicking button

Tags: html, buttonclick

i need to create html code, in which if user selects an item from drop down list and click button then it will go to respective link.

```
<select name="myList">
<option value="Google" />Google
<option value="yahoo" />yahoo
<option value="Ask" />Ask
</select>
```

if user selects Google from drop down list and clicks button, then page should be redirected to **www.google.com** and if it selects yahoo and clicks button should go to **www.yahoo.com**

I would like to mention that I need The button in this scenario.
I don't want to go respective site on drop down selection.Only after clicking the button.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: no..i need it for my blog on blogspot..i m not sure it supports asp.net commnads ...so need it simple..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select name="myList" id="ddlMyList">
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="http://www.ask.com">Ask</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Go To Site!" onclick="NavigateToSite()" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function NavigateToSite(){
    var ddl = document.getElementById("ddlMyList");
    var selectedVal = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

    window.location = selectedVal;
}
```

You could also open the site in a new window by doing this:

```
function NavigateToSite(){
    var ddl = document.getElementById("ddlMyList");
    var selectedVal = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

    window.open(selectedVal)
}
```

As a side note, your option tags are not properly formatted. You should never use the <... /> shortcut when a tag contains content.

Comment: Thanx a lot..it worked perfectly...Thanx for the New Window code..that really helped me !!

Answer (score 5):

First, change the option values to the URL you want to target:

```
<option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
<option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
<option value="http://www.ask.com">Ask</option>
```

Next, add an ID to the select so you can target it:

```
<select name="myList" id="myList">
```

Finally, add an onclick method to the select control to handle the redirect:

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.location.href=document.getElementById('myList').value">
```

Comment: Add a button to this answer and it's as perfect as mine ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="myList">
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="http://www.ask.com">Ask</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="window.location=document.myList.value" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript, you can attach an `onclick` event to the button. In the event handler, you can use an `if` statement to check which value was selected in the `select` list, and use `window.location` to redirect the user to the appropriate URL.

I would suggest changing the `value` of the `option` elements to be the required URL, and you can then simply grab the value and go to that URL, instead of having to check which option was selected.

Answer (score -4):

```
onclick()="window.location.href='page.html'"
```